# Setting default value for OptionSet in CRM 2011 Dialog

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a requirement to populate the default value for an OptionSet in a Prompt-Response based on a value pulled in from a query within the Dialog.  However, the default value field is disabled for both types of OptionSet.

Can anyone confirm if this is the correct behaviour as I can't think of any reason why you wouldn't be able to assign a default to an OptionSet at runtime?

This will mean duplicating the entire Page as I can't even add a Condition statement to conditionally use different Prompt-Responses unless anyone can offer a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

When you do query that means you are getting a set of values, even if it's a single one.
So, yo can pupulate an Option Set from Query but not set a default value.

Anyway, default value field is not for OptionSets it's for text, numeric and DateTime responses.

I am not quite understand your last question.
Could you give more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Long time since the question got asked.

The simplest answer is that you can´t set a default value to the option set.

However another sollution instead of duplicating the page, and that may be useful in a case like this, is a workaround with two queries.

1. Declare a variable of the type you want to be dynamic in the Query for the Option set.
2. Set the variable to a value that would give you the default Option set value you´re looking for.
3. Query for the data that you want to use with the dynamic type you want to use.
4. Check number of records the query returns.
5. If number of records is more than 0 you set the value of the variable to the dynamic vaule used in the query
6. Query for the same data again(!), this time with the variable instead of the previously used dynamic value, and use this one for the Option Set.

The result is: If you get hits from your query, the hits will be shown in the option set. If you don't get hits the "default" value will be shown.

Also don't think there is any reason why you wouldn't be able to set a default value for the Option set. Especially since the page locks up if the query used for the option set returns no hits.

Cheers.
/Henrik

Answer (score 0):

Further to this I have come across a situation today where I have used some fetchxml to query data in a dialog and are now wanting to store that value within a variable but appears I cant and can only use this to show fields within an option set.

I appreciate the xml is returning a record and not a field but there must be away I can return first or default and store the returned value in a variable.